# get client side element ID of a Field in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

In asp.net, server side control have a property called ClientID, which can be used to get the id that template engine generated for a server side control, is there a similar thing in SilverStripe, to get the id of the input element rather than its .field wrapper?

thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the standard FormFields that Silverstripe ships with (eg. TextField, CheckboxField etc) or other custom fields that extend `FormField`?

Comment: yes, standard FormFields

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the **ID** method of **FormField**

http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-FormField.html

In your templates, you should be able to use

```
$Fields.FieldByName(FieldName).ID
```

Comment: I cannot make it in template, but I have tried in code as this `$fields->dataFieldByName('AnotherField')->setAttribute('data-attribute', $isTrueField->ID());`
And the output is just the "IsTrue", not include the form prefixes...
sorry i have no idea how to post a well formatted code at here, so I put more information in gist: https://gist.github.com/Ariex/57ffc1db828feedda649

Comment: Maybe try $id = $isTrueField->form->FormName() . '_' . $isTrueForm->ID();  If you look at the code for ID() it should return the form name http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-FormField.html#250-266

Comment: Perhaps there is no form defined. Try a Debug::dump($isTrueForm->form);